# MYSQL DATE Is it possible after i insert the date today then in another column it is + 5 months?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I need your helps guys and if it is possible what kind of data type im gonna use in mysql? Im creating a system information system so when an employee gets hired
i will compare if his/her datehired and contractEnd will equal and if its equal it will prompt a user a message. please help me.

Comment: just a column in my database im gathering ideas so i can start in date. can you help me?

Comment: What is your MySQL version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement is something like this..

You have a table with two columns where both data type is `DATE`.
And you need to add five months to the colunm1 value and insert it in to the column2.

In MySQL Server Version **5.7.5** and above, you can try something like this..

when you create the table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE YourTable( 
    -> column1 DATE,
    -> column2DATE AS (DATE_ADD(column1 ,INTERVAL 5 MONTH)),
    ->);
```

Or You can Create a View to generate the result as you need (In Older Versions)

```
CREATE VIEW YourView
   AS 
  SELECT Column1 AS datehired ,
DATE_ADD(column1 ,INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AS contractEnd 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: let me try after my lunch break thanks! by the way im using datepicker is it possible?

Comment: you mean, you are using datepicker in front end of your application?

Comment: It won't be a problem to you, And this answer is only applicable to MySQL versions above 5.7.5

Comment: Do you need to store that value in the db, If not you can create a view for that table to retrieve what ever the data you need

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can do your checking by using the view.

Comment: wait sir i will try it to  your such a great help!

Comment: its working sir what if i have many employee that means i have more view?

Comment: i get it i will just make it show in the front end thank you bro

Comment: what do you mean by many employee? 
I think you are mentioning about multiple employees,If so this will work fro multiple records also.. Because many employees 'll be multiple records in your table.